# Problems with webix.require Webix3.1

Tags: javascript, webix

I use Webix2.5, I use webix.require to other file.

In main.js

```
webix.require("jSFiles/FileOne.js");
webix.require("jSFiles/FileTwo.js");
webix.require("jSFiles/FileTree.js");
webix.require("jSFiles/funOne.js");
webix.require("jSFiles/funTwo.js");
```

change into Webix 3.1 and webix.require not working.

I read the [documentation](http://docs.webix.com/desktop__whats_new_3_0.html), indicates that:

- Webix.require() returns promise.
- Webix.require do not recognize full http paths.hs.

I do not know if you mentioned has something to do with my problem or an error on the version.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like they moved from synchronous to asynchronous require. Meaning you probably have to handle it like `webix.require("...").then(function() { ... })`. This is a guess, since I don't use webix and apparently they have very poor documentation.

Comment: It corresponds to what you say, below is the answer. Thank you @user2867288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Webix 3.x, require uses async.mode by default.

To force the old behavior use:

```
webix.require("jSFiles/files.js", true)
```

thanks to [@kozhemak](https://twitter.com/kozhemak)

Comment: `webix.require("jSFiles/files.js", true).catch(e => console.error(e));`, otherwise it may die silently